# New to XCode - How to create a class?

Tags: xcode, class

I am new to Xcode, running version 8.0.

Right now I am going trough [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RP4f9beidc&list=PLAE85DE8440AA6B83&index=42)

tutorial. (I am programming in C++). There the author is creating a class. Since he is not using Xcode and the other answers to a similar question are dealing with an older version, I am asking myself if someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to create a new c++ file in Xcode

---

To be able to run c++ files in Xcode you need to create a new project first.

[image: File -> New -> Project]

[image: macOS -> Command Line Tool]

**Then in your project you can add files using the guide below**

[image: File -> New -> File]

[image: macOS -> C++ file]

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a side menu with your project -> new file -> ios source on left panel -> swift file on a right panel. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention that I am working with C++, still working like this?

Comment: Yes a c++ file. Not a swift.